# Login timeout connecting to Azure sql form azure function app with Python

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

Hi I'm trying to use a function app to connect to an azure sql server, fetch some data and push it to Google Big Query.

The function works when I am using the VsCode extension and run it with "Attach to Python functions"

But when I push it to azure, the function fails with the error "Login timeout expired"

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.getIntrestPushToGBQ Result: Failure
Exception: OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I've set the firewall to allow azure resources access.

Here is the code I'm using to connect

```
driver = "{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}"
server = "my-org.database.windows.net,1433"
database = "Mydatabase"
user = os.getenv("sqlUser")
password = os.getenv("sqlPassword")


params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(
    f"DRIVER={driver};"
    f"SERVER={server};"
    f"DATABASE={database};"
    f"UID={user};"
    f"PWD={password};"
    f"Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword"
)

engine = sa.create_engine(f"mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={params}")

df = pd.read_sql(
            """SELECT
        count(DISTINCT parentcontactid) as antall,
        [marketareaname],
        [ismember],

        CAST([createdon] as DATE) as date
        FROM [Integration_CRM].[Lead]
        GROUP BY [marketareaname], [ismember], CAST([createdon] as DATE)
        ORDER BY CAST([createdon] as DATE)""",
            engine,
        )
```

The functionapp is running on Linux

Comment: did using IP address resolved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the  `PYODBC`  connection Error:

Try using **IP Address** of server e.g.  `server = '129.0.0.1’` When using a **port**, use something like or `129.0.0.1,1233`

Try removing extra attributes like "authentication" and all of them, then verify again.

**Example of Connect Azure SQL Database using Python:**

```py
import pyodbc
import pandas as  pd
server  =  'azuredemosqldemo.database.windows.net'
database  =  'azuredemodatabase'
username  =  'sqladmin'
password  =  '********'
driver=  '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

with pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER=tcp:'+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+  password)  as  conn:

df=pd.read_sql_query('Select Top 5 ProductID, Name, ProductNumber from SalesLT.Product order by productid',  conn)

print(df)
```

Also see [Connecting to Azure SQL Server using Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/connect-to-azure-sql-server-using-python-76eba1fb458b)

Reference : [connecting to SQL using pyodbc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15)